# Sync available status between Slack <-> S4B or MS Teams <-> Skype

Tags: slack, skype, skype-for-business

Right now we use 3 different programs in my company for communicating. We use

1. Slack
2. Skype for business
3. Skype

The problem is that if I got a call or have a meeting in Slack the other software shows me as available and people try to call me as well... Is there any software that automatically shares my status between all these programs?

Call in S4B -> Slack: Change status to "busy"